# Tkinter Callback exception

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, yolov4

I was importing a dataset in bbox_tool and for that i downloaded a code for bbox_tool. But while trying to import a image from the directory, it isn't getting imported. This is what I am getting in my command prompt.

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MY DELL\Downloads\YOLO-v4-Implementation-on-Custom-Dataset-main\YOLO-v4-Implementation-on-Custom-Dataset-main\bbox_tool.py", line 333, in nextImage
    self.saveImage()
  File "C:\Users\MY DELL\Downloads\YOLO-v4-Implementation-on-Custom-Dataset-main\YOLO-v4-Implementation-on-Custom-Dataset-main\bbox_tool.py", line 256, in saveImage
    with open(self.labelfilename, 'w') as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the code in the bbox_tool python file:

```
def saveImage(self):
     if self.file_will_not_remove:
        with open(self.labelfilename, 'w') as f:
            if self.save_to_yolo_format.get():
                for bbox in self.bboxList:
                    f.write(' '.join(map(str, bbox)) + '\n')
            else:
                f.write('%d\n' %len(self.bboxList))
                for bbox in self.bboxList:
                    f.write(' '.join(map(str, bbox)) + '\n')
        self.print_log('Label saved to ' + self.labelname)
```